# Different Interpretation of TH Box Model Between Browsers

Tags: css, html-table, cross-browser

I'm noticing discrepancies between browsers in how the width of a `TH` tag is interpreted, specifically whether or not padding is included in the width calculation.

I am building a reusable library for quickly generating and styling tables (for tabular data, of course). This means that I have full control over the code I generate, but that I need to actually solve the problem versus finding a hack for a particular instance.

**Simplest Description of the Problem**

A `TH` in IE9 and FF is sized based on its padding + width (as expected). Chrome and Safari *include* the padding in the width, leading to undesirable results.

For example, if the cell is set to 16px wide + 4px of padding, IE9 correctly displays the cell as 20px wide. Chrome displays it as 16px wide.

Here is a JS Fiddle showing the differences: http://jsfiddle.net/CZnau/

You can see how the last cell is sized differently between browsers.

**Notes**

- I am aware of box-sizing and even though the default is to **not** include the padding in width calculation of a cell, setting `box-sizing: content-box` explicitly does not fix the problem.
- The fiddle shows a fixed layout table. I wish to use `table-layout: fixed` to handle display correctly in other scenarios. Specifically, my actual implementation uses text-overflow, wrapping management, and variable width layouts. In my testing using a fixed layout is the only reliable way to make all my requirements play together nicely. Plus, fixed layout tables potentially render more quickly.
- I have tried setting the width explicitly on each `TD`, but this does not fix the issue (perhaps it conflicts with the fixed layout table?)

In case you want more details around **why** I need a fixed layout table, try this fiddle with and without `table-layout: fixed` and note the differences. With a fixed layout, the table is correctly sized to 100% and truncates text elegantly, even with a variable width cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/6GPmY/

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't support `box-sizing: content-box;` yet, not even in their Aurora Version.

Until then you can use `-moz-box-sizing`:

```
th, td {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6GPmY/138/)

Comment: +1 for taking the time. However, look at this fiddle (the difference is more obvious with a smaller width): http://jsfiddle.net/PLa6y/. In Chrome, the last TH is sized to 1px, but in FF the padding is honored, with or without the box-sizing style and the cell is 17px wide.